# Reactive Java: change window size at runtime

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have a Flux emitting items every 1 seconds, on repeat. How can I change the window size dynamically?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Duration interval = Duration.ofSeconds(1);

    Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
    flux
            .repeat()
            // on each emit from the publisher,
            // a batch of a dynamic size is read
            // could be just 1 item, 3 items, or even more
            .window(calcWindowSize()))
            .concatMap(Flux::collectList)
            // since we only emit every 1 second
            // the window size changes over time
            .delayElements(interval)
            .doOnNext(batch -> {
                log.info("Processed batch: " + batch + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            })
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(10_000);
}

private static int calcWindowSize() {
    // this calculation is a little more complex in reality
    // so let's just use some random int here
    return RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 10);
}
```

The code above is NOT working but hopefully illustrates what I want to achieve. I tried using `windowWhen` but don't understand its syntax. If I cannot dynamically change the window size, can I recreate the Flux maybe and continue from where I left on the second before?

Comment: There are few ways. You could use `window` with a `Publisher`, or use `windowUntil`, or even implement a very custom logic with `reduce`. But it all depends on what's your exact problem you want to solve.

Comment: the problem I wanna solve is that I wanna scale the window size over time up and down. the available window should be calculated by a simple function that returns an int. I tried with windowWhen but not sure  how it's supposed to be used. not sure about window Until either. I'd appreciate some sample code how to do this

Comment: It's hard to answer without understanding what didn't work for you. Any of them could work for the general situation as you explained. If you tell what exactly prevented you from using one of them, then maybe someone can give you a suggestion how you can fix it

Comment: I just don't understand what I need to pass to windowWhen at all. The signatures with all the generics are just so confusing (like basically all Reactor signatures). The actual implementation how I calculate the window size should not matter I think

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of the logic behind the window boundaries? like how you want to split those strings into windows

Comment: ok I updated the question with some more code and comments, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In general, when your window boundaries depends on items, like their count, etc., then `windowUntil` with a `Predicate<T>` would be a simplest choice.

It gets all the elements one by one, and returns `true` when the window should close. You can run a counter or other logic inside the predicate.

For your synthetic example something like this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Duration interval = Duration.ofSeconds(1);

    Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
    flux
            .repeat()
            // on each emit from the publisher,
            // a batch of a dynamic size is read
            // could be just 1 item, 3 items, or even more
            .windowUntil(boundaries())
            .concatMap(Flux::collectList)
            // since we only emit every 1 second
            // the window size changes over time
            .delayElements(interval)
            .doOnNext(batch -> {
                log.info("Processed batch: " + batch + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            })
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(10_000); 
}

private static Predicate<String> boundaries() {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(calcWindowSize());
    return {
       boolean done = counter.decrementAndGet() <= 0;
       if (done) {
          counter.set(calcWindowSize());
       }
       done
    }
}

private static int calcWindowSize() {
    // this calculation is a little more complex in reality
    // so let's just use some random int here
    return RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 10); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a combination of `skip` and `take` works for me. The `tick` is passed to calculateCount so I can do some fancy calculation for the next batch size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J").repeat();
    Flux<Long> timerFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    AtomicInteger previous = new AtomicInteger(0);
    timerFlux
            .flatMap(tick -> {
                int count = calculateCount(tick);
                int skipCount = previous.getAndAdd(count);
                // skip previously picked items, take next batch size
                return flux.skip(skipCount).take(count);
            })
            .doOnNext(batch -> {
                log.info("Processed batch: " + batch + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            })
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(10_000);
}


private static int calculateCount(Long seconds) {
    // Implement your logic here to calculate the subset size
    // For example, you can return a constant value or a dynamic calculation
    return 3; // Return a constant value of 3 as an example
}
```

The input string is on repeat and I skip all items that have previously been emitted.

Comment: that's a very ineffective way of doing that. First, you do multiple subscriptions, which usually is not even available, and second you waste a lot of data. So the complexity is something like `O(n*m)` where `m` is the number of windows, though there is no reason to make it slower that `O(n)`